# How to make div's width fit content not window

Tags: html, css

In the following code, how to make "#wrap" width fit its childs width, and not to limit to browser window bounds ?

## HTML

```
<div id="wrap">WRAP
    <div id="menu">MENU</div>
    <div id="large-content">LARGE CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#wrap{background: #eee;}
#large-content{background: #f1c40f; width: 1000px; height: 300px}
#menu{background: #2c3e50; width: 100%; height: 50px}
```

## JSFIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/67egnpho/1/

Comment: `display:inline:block` - that might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The childs width is 100% so currently it is fitting it.

Adding `display: inline-block;` will keep it inline with it's contents.

```
#wrap{background: #eee; display: inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<div>` element is block level by default, it occupies the entire space of its parent container, which is `<body>` in this case.

You can set to `#wrap {display: inline-block;}` or `#wrap {display: table;}` so that it will be flowed with surrounding content.

One other way is using `#wrap {width: fit-content;)`, see [support tables](https://caniuse.com/#search=fit-content).

Answer (score 0):

Either inline or inline-block if you want wrap to act like a block itself.

HTML :

```
<div id="wrap">WRAP
   <div id="menu">MENU</div>
   <div id="large-content">LARGE CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap{background: #eee;display: inline-block;} 
or   
#wrap{background: #eee;display: inline-block;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/67egnpho/4/) what you are looking for?

Adding:

```
position: absolute;
```

to the parent and floating the children will make the parent stretch to fit the children.